# Can you conditionally negate a function in PHP?

Tags: php

For example

```
$x = true;
return (($x ? "!" : "" ). is_null(NULL));
```

This obviously doesn't work, is there a way to do it?

The goal is to refactor this

```
       $var == true
        ? array_filter($labels, function($v){return str_contains($v, 'return');})
        : array_filter($labels, function($v){return !str_contains($v, 'return');});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a plain-English description of what the function here *should* do? I'm not sure if I'm just mis-reading or something else, but it's not clear to me what *exactly* you're going for as an end result here, and screams XY problem at first glance.

Comment: `return ($x ? is_null($var) : !is_null($var));`

Comment: Your edit makes the question _much more confusing_. `is_null(NULL)` will simply be compiled as `true`, so the expression becomes `$x ? false : true`, or `! $x`.

Comment: I have added another edit, hope it's clearer now

Comment: Well, the meaningless `is_null(NULL)` is still there, you should have stuck with `is_null($var)`; and if `$labels` is an array, then `$labels == true` is a particularly awkward way of writing `count($labels) > 0` , but you already had three answers before the edits, and they're all still valid as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry the ternary is not on $labels but on a variable that can be either true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of describing boolean combinations is as a *truth table* listing the possible inputs and outputs. In this case:

| $x | is_null($var) | Desired result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | false |
| false | true | true |
| true | false | true |
| true | true | false |

So, the result you want is "either `$x` is true, or `is_null($var)` is true, but not both".

Looking [in the PHP manual under "logical operators"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), we see that that's the definition of the `xor` operator, so you could write this:

```
return $x xor is_null($var);
```

An intermediate variable and simple `if` statement as shown in [Justinas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70772899/157957) is probably a lot more readable, though. **Readability is extremely important in programming**, because code is read far more times than it's written.

Comment: While very nicely illustrated with a truth table and entirely correct, I find `!=` to be more readily understandable than the somewhat obscure `xor`, but that may entirely depend on your frame of mind…

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I've upvoted your answer, but as I mention, anything other than a simple `if` is getting into the realms of "cute, but probably going to slow you down when you read it back".

Comment: That is what I meant, it worked :)

Thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

You can, but with different approach: first execute function and then check if it needs to be inverted

```php
$result = is_null($var);

if ($x) {
   // invert result from e.g. true to false
   $result = !$result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`is_null` returns a boolean. `$x` is a boolean. Compare both booleans:

```
return is_null($var) != $x;
```